# Is it possible to launch already installed android app as kisok app after rebooting my ChromeBook?

Tags: kiosk-mode, chromebook

I have a chromebook and have G-suite account.

1. I have enabled android apps on chromeOS
2. Approved one android app from managed google play
3. Added that approved android app as kiosk app

After this I have sideloaded my debug apk build(Which is already approved in above steps) https://www.howtogeek.com/260075/how-to-sideload-an-android-app-from-an-apk-on-a-chromebook/

Now i have rebooted my chromebook and went into kisok mode.

The question is would it be possible to launch my debug apk in kiosk mode?